# Why does this enumerator.to_a returns []?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I just encounter this piece of code

```
Enumerator.new((1..100), :take, 5).to_a
# => []
```

Does anyone know why it returns an empty array and not an array of 5 integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs, [`Enumerator#new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-c-new):

```
new(obj, method = :each, *args)
```

> In the second, deprecated, form, a generated Enumerator iterates over
>   the given object using the given method with the given arguments
>   passed.
>
> Use of this form is discouraged. Use Kernel#enum_for or Kernel#to_enum
>   instead.

This second usage (which you should not use according to the documentation), needs a `each`-like method (that's it, one that yields values). `take` *returns* values, but does not *yield* them, so you get an empty enumerable.

Note that in Ruby 2 it will be plain simple to perform a lazy `take`:

```
2.0.0dev> xs = (1..100).lazy.take(5)
#=> #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator::Lazy: 1..100>:take(5)>
2.0.0dev> xs.to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: *"so you get an empty enumerable."* but then why do I get `Enumerator.new((1..100), :take, 5).each(&method(:puts)); #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` ?

Comment: Good question, but in fact it has nothing to do with calling the method `puts`, using an empty block for the `each` results in the same output. I don't know why is that.